# How can I sort dictionary by an array guide when I have order keys?

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort a dictionary by key if I have a second array guide where I had all sorted key of dictionary?

Example:

```
let dict = ["35": "a", "398":"b", "98":"c"]
```

```
let guideArray = ["398","35","98"]
```

so I want a sorted dict like:

```
let sortDict = ["398": "b", "35":"a", "98":"c"]
```

Comment: Dictionary aren't ordered. Usually, your model is wrong. You could use an array (that can be sorted), handling custom struct/class or tuples. There is a OrderedDictionary in Swift Collections + (via SPM or in a recent Swift version), but in my opinion, you should avoid it when beginning, as dictionary are like that in many languages (and in terms of algorithm that you'll see or code to debug).

Comment: You don't need to sort it since your array is sorted. Iterate over the array instead of the dictionary when needed and use the array element to access the dictionary in the "right" order.

Answer (score -2):

A dictionary is not a sorted type of table by definition so cannot be sorted and nothing ensures that the order of the elements won't change. I don't think is the best approach.
You could make an array and add the elements there if what matters for you is the order.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, it’s probably better to post this as a comment.